# Blurred images by default, reveal when being hovered?

Tags: css, image, animation, hover, blur

I'd like to embed images that are blurred by default using CSS (source image files are not blurred ofc). When the user hovers over an image it should be revealed. It would be awesome if it would have an animation on it as well. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

[**CSS filters**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter) (MDN Reference) can do this

```css
img {
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
  filter: blur(10px);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-filter .5s linear;
  transition: -webkit-filter .5s linear;
  transition: filter .5s linear;
  transition: filter .5s linear, -webkit-filter .5s linear;
}
img:hover {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0);
  filter: blur(0)
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/460/300" alt="" />
```